# How to determine the length of a .gif animation in milliseconds

Tags: javascript, image, gif, animated-gif

Is there an easy way to figure out approximately how long a .gif image takes to play one time in Javascript?

Comment: In what programming language/platform/environment?

Comment: Not very concerned about the environment as I don't really need the value programmatically I just need to determine the approximate time the gif needs to take to play once in milliseconds. However, I am implementing the number I would get back from this in javascript.

Comment: If you're not concerned about doing this programmatically, then this question is off-topic.

Comment: I actually just need to get the value of this for one gif in some way/shape/form regardless of how I get it. If there is an application that will tell me this already I could use that, if not I could use Javascript to do this. Either way works for me. Thanks for the help so far!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `identify` command from [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) can give this information:

```
$ identify -verbose file.gif | grep 'Elapsed time'

  Elapsed time: 0:01.080
  Elapsed time: 0:01.150
  Elapsed time: 0:01.230
```

...

```
  Elapsed time: 0:04.250
  Elapsed time: 0:04.330
  Elapsed time: 0:04.399
  Elapsed time: 0:04.480
```

The last line printed should be the total length of the animation.

Comment: Running it three times gives Elapsed time: 0:02.780,  Elapsed time: 0:02.840 and Elapsed time: 0:02.810.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer doesn't give the exact result. `Elapsed time` is like a real world clock while ImageMagick runs the animation. What you want is the `Delay` field for each frame and sum them up.

```
$ identify -verbose fail.gif  | grep Delay

Delay: 10x100
Delay: 10x100
Delay: 10x100
Delay: 10x100
Delay: 15x100
Delay: 10x100
Delay: 10x100
Delay: 10x100
Delay: 10x100
Delay: 10x100
Delay: 10x100
Delay: 10x100
Delay: 10x100
Delay: 10x100
Delay: 10x100
Delay: 10x100
Delay: 10x100
Delay: 10x100
Delay: 10x100
Delay: 10x100
Delay: 10x100
Delay: 33x100
Delay: 10x100
Delay: 10x100
Delay: 10x100
```

Where `33x100` is a delay of 330ms.

**Edited by Mark Setchell**

You can actually extract the delay parameter somewhat more surgically (than by using `grep`) with the `%T` escape:

[image]

```
identify -format "%T\n" animation.gif 

8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
26
```

And get the total with `awk` like this:

```
identify -format "%T\n" anomation.gif | awk '{t+=$0} END{print t " centiseconds"}'
183 centiseconds
```

Comment: I added a bit more - I hope you don't mind. Have a vote too!

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks. Also for the term "centisecond" ;)

Answer (score 2):

**You can pass gif file to following function, which will return duration value**

```
isGifAnimated(file) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        let fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        fileReader.onload = (event) => {
          let arr = new Uint8Array(<ArrayBuffer>fileReader.result);
          let duration = 0;
          for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] == 0x21
              && arr[i + 1] == 0xF9
              && arr[i + 2] == 0x04
              && arr[i + 7] == 0x00) {
              const delay = (arr[i + 5] << 8) | (arr[i + 4] & 0xFF)
              duration += delay < 2 ? 10 : delay;
            }
          }
          resolve(duration / 100);
        }

      } catch (e) {
        reject(e);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: it really helps and works smoothly could please explain me how is this working?

Answer (score 1):

I tried ImageMagick `identify` but it didn't give me the correct duration.

I found another reliable way using [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/)

`exiftool -Duration image.gif`

It will print out the duration in seconds:

`Duration                        : 0.48 s`