# Total Duration of Animation on a gif

Tags: animation, imagemagick, gif, animated-gif

Currently we use a stopwatch to determine the Total duration of Animation on the gif banners.

Already referred to the imagemagick solutions - [How to determine the length of a .gif animation in milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9812589/how-to-determine-the-length-of-a-gif-animation-in-milliseconds)

**Sample gif banner:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTz79.gif

---

**Actual Stats:-**

Iterations = 20

Duration - Frame 1 = 0.5 secs

Duration - Frame 2 = 0.5 secs

Total Time = 20*(0.5+0.5) = 20 secs

---

**Stats provided by ImageMagick:-**

Using - `identify -verbose betsy.gif | grep -E 'Iterations|Elapsed'`

Iterations: 19

Elapsed time: 0:01.000

Elapsed time: 0:01.040

Total Time = 1.040*19 = 19.76 secs

---

Is there any other way (except for using a physical stopwatch) to find the exact Duration of the Animation programmatically?

Comment: I think you have an old version if ImageMagick. I use v6.9.3 and it correctly reports 1 second for your file. Try also `identify -format '%T\n' betsy.gif` for individual frame lengths in centiseconds.

Answer (score 4):

Use exiftool like:

```
$ exiftool splash.gif 
ExifTool Version Number         : 11.76
File Name                       : splash.gif
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 1062 kB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2020:06:18 10:04:16+02:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2020:06:18 09:51:54+02:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2020:06:18 10:04:16+02:00
File Permissions                : rw-r--r--
File Type                       : GIF
File Type Extension             : gif
MIME Type                       : image/gif
GIF Version                     : 89a
Image Width                     : 950
Image Height                    : 140
Has Color Map                   : Yes
Color Resolution Depth          : 1
Bits Per Pixel                  : 1
Background Color                : 0
Animation Iterations            : Infinite
Frame Count                     : 149
Duration                        : 4.96 s
Image Size                      : 950x140
Megapixels                      : 0.133
```

You can find Duration in seconds.

Comment: For reference: I tested with Exiftool 10.80 and it gets the duration incorrect. I'll try again when I have a later version.